# Jenkins nightly build only on new code

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

Is it possible to have Jenkins run a nightly build, but to not run the nightly build if there is no new code? For example, most of the days we have new code that would need to be analyzed, but ever so often we don't commit code that day (perhaps the dev did not come in), and I would like to avoid clogging up the artifacts and analysis with the redundant builds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can definitely be done. Under the job options, there should be a "Poll SCM" option under "Build Triggers".

Here's a video explaining it better:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R0gyFokexks

Comment: Right, but I want it to build nightly, unless there were no commits during that day.

Comment: That's exactly what it does. Just configure it to poll the SCM nightly. See minute 2:35 of the video linked in the answer.

Comment: Right, I am thick. I see what you mean, thanks for your help.